# Select Line or index in Textbox System windows form

Tags: powershell

I would like to do this :

If I click on "Martin" all word at the same lines like (Martin luter king) will be select or if I click on "king" all word at the same lines like (The king of the pop) will be select

Martin lutter king

The king of the pop

Tupac was the best one

Almost of the code has been found.

```
$richtextBox1.SelectionStart = $richtextbox1.GetFirstCharIndexOfCurrentLine()  
$richtextBox1.SelectionLength = ??????
```

I don't know how to find the last character from the current line

Comment: That is incomprehensible. Please create a [mcve], update your question with that code and describe what you expected the code to do and what it actually does.

Comment: I don't think you can perform selection with line breaks. I.e. leaving not matching lines of text unselected. Like lines 1,3,4 matching, lines 2,5 not matching. Perhaps, instead you could think of `SelectionColor` for matching word lines.

Answer (score 0):

I did it after several try one line

Martin lutter king

The king of the pop

Tupac was the best one

$result=$richtextbox1.Lines[$richtextbox1.GetLineFromCharIndex($richtextbox1.GetFirstCharIndexOfCurrentLine())]

write-host $result

When I click on "was" or "tupac" ,this text "Tupac was the best one" has been selected
that's work for other lines